# Is there a crosswalk between U.S. Census 1990 SF3 and 2000 SF3?

Tags: usa, us-census

Is there a source that compares the tables from the U.S. Census 1990 SF3 and 2000? Something like the data provided in [this Census 2000 to ACS5 comparison tool](https://www.census.gov/acs/www/guidance/comparing-acs-data/acscensus-table-lookup/).

Some information is provided by [Columbia University Library](http://library.columbia.edu/locations/dssc/data/cen90_00_compare.html). The [Longitudinal Tract Database](https://s4.ad.brown.edu/projects/diversity/Researcher/LTBDDload/Default.aspx) also provides limited table level crosswalks in their codebook.